# Ignoring modules other than own in testoob coverage reporting

Tags: python, code-coverage

I use testoob in the following way:

```
def suite():
    import unittest
    return unittest.TestLoader().loadTestsFromNames([
         'my_module.my_unittest_class',
         'my_module.my_other_unittest_class',
    ])

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import testoob
    testoob.main(defaultTest="suite")
```

And then run the unittest suite with the following:

```
python my_unittest.py --coverage=normal
```

This however will also print code coverage figures of all modules that my module and unittest depends on, which I'm not interested in at all. How can I configure testoob to only report coverage for my own module?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up overriding the private `_should_cover_frame` function in the `testoob` `Coverage` class and comparing the frame's file path to my module. Not the nicest solution, but at least it works.

```
from testoob.coverage import Coverage
orig_should_cover = Coverage._should_cover_frame
def my_should_cover_frame(self, frame):
    from os.path import abspath
    filename = abspath(frame.f_code.co_filename)
    if filename.find('my_module') == -1:
        return False
    else:
        return orig_should_cover(self, frame)
Coverage._should_cover_frame = my_should_cover_frame
```